# CSS: Div boxes aren't even when using 50%

Tags: html, css

I have two div boxes that I want side by side. I am using a border of 2px on the outside of them, and on the inside of the boxes I am using 1px (so as to make a 2px appearance of the inside borders as well). When I use:

```
height: auto;
width: 50%;
```

The boxes are not even so as to be able to use a calc css rule on them. They over lap by five pixels. If I delete 5px on the first one it works, but then I have some left over space in the side that I annoying and doesn't look very clean. Here is a JSFiddle of what I have: [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/k7ht7jv8/)

Thanks, DoubleDogg6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `box-sizing: border-box;`

add following css

```
#box1,#box2{box-sizing: border-box;}
```

**update jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/k7ht7jv8/1/

more about box-sizing property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 0):

To clarify [Cattla's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27613404/3019302), elements typically use `content-box` box-sizing, meaning that set widths and heights only affect the inner height and width of an element, inside the element’s border and padding. `padding-box` includes the element’s padding and `border-box` includes the element‘s padding and border width.

Since you're using borders and set widths, you should set the elements’ box-sizing to `border-box`.

[box-sizing - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this without box-sizing is to use an outer div for each div. Only add border, margin and 
padding to the inner div. Set the width in the outer div.

Style:

```
div.percent50 {
  width:50%;
}
div.bordered {
  border: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="percent50">
   <div class="bordered">

   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="percent50">
   <div class="bordered">

   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your border is making the boxes wider than 50% each (i.e. the border width is added to the element width by default). To avoid this, you can change the `box-sizing` for the page (or for the individual elements:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

or

```
#box1, #box2 { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k7ht7jv8/2/)**